# Updating appcelerator caused android app to crash

Tags: javascript, android, titanium, appcelerator

I am having issues with appcelerator, anybody with pervious experience had any issues with it? if it wasn't for a 3 year project on appcelerator I would have switched. Anyway i believe to have fixed the error just need clarifying why i need to change this now when it worked perfectly before. This is the error that appears when I try and load a new window.

```
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [6174,104116] ----- Titanium Javascript Runtime Error -----
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [1,104117] - In ti:/view.js:19,10
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [0,104117] - Message: Uncaught Error: Cannot add window/tabGroup to a view.
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [1,104118] - Source:          throw new Error("Cannot add window/tabGroup to a view.");
```

to fix the issue I have to switch all of my tags from `<Window>` to `<View>`. I believe the issue is to do with the fact you can't have two windows loaded at the same time, I just need clarification why it now suddenly has stopped working!!!

**UPDATE**

When I change the xml to `<View>` the android app will run fine, however this causes the iOS app to now no run, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

So the error is pretty straightforward, you cannot add a `<Window>` to a View. So... the root needs to be either a `<Window>` or `<NavigationWindow>`.
On Android the navigationWindow doesn't exist. So you need to have Android specific UI, or iOS specific UI. You can also use the commonJS module `xp.ui` for Titanium to get NavigationWindow to work on Android: https://github.com/FokkeZB/UTiL/blob/master/docs/xp.ui.md (just follow instructions how to install).

An app needs a Window or NavigationWindow as a root to work properly. So... having neither of these will make the app not work.

So I recommend the module, and then use NavigationWindow > Window construction.

Comment: Okay, i will read up on it. Do you know why this worked then all of a sudden stopped after an update i believe its to do with the SDK. The previous was 3.8.2.GA and now running at 5.5.0.GA

Comment: Haven't heard anything changing in since 3.#.

Comment: The only thing i could think of is moving the project and creating a new workspace, could that have an effect?

Comment: i managed to fix the issue. i had to downgrade the node.js from 4.4.0 to 0.12.7 and then downgrade the SDK from 5.5.0.GA to 4.0.0.GA. I can't go above that otherwise the error will occur. seems to be an issue with newer versions. will contact appcelerator about it.